# How does "суметь + infinitive" differ in usage from "смочь + infinitive"?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Я **сумею** о себе позаботиться. --- {суметь}
>
> Но нет ничего такого, с чем мы не **смогли** бы справиться, да? --- {смочь}

It seems that both "суметь + infinitive" and "смочь  + infinitive" means "be able to do something" or "manage to do something", but I wonder if they are simply interchangeable in the two sentences above? Or do they carry nuances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By and large they're interchangeable.

One slight difference they may have is in that **`я сумею`** implies ability exercised  in spite of any obstacles or adverse circumstances, it has a resilience undertone.

**`я смогу`** just indicates general ability without going into any further specifics as to the mode of exercising it.

Comment: Hi. Incidentally, how should I pronounce the "г" sound in "ниче**г**о тако**г**о"? Some native speakers utter "g", while others "v". Is it a regional difference or something?

Comment: Hi, in Russian as "v", in Ukrainian it would be a fricative "g" which sounds like "h". As "g" it's also pronounced in Church-Slavonic, but then it's not Russian. I'm not aware of cases of the second pronunciation among native speakers, unless its a purposeful distortion

Comment: It's just I can/ will be able to vs. I know how, will find a way to (will manage to). Just look in any good dictionary to get an idea of the difference. 
СУМЕТЬ--(+ инф.) be able (+ to inf); manage (+ to inf); succeed (in ger)
СМОЧЬ--be able to, prove able to
And that's it--anybody that speaks English now knows when to use one and not the other--no need for philosophy.

Comment: well i guess i ventured into descriptive explanation because the inquirer  had used both variants `to be able` and `to manage` as possible translations for both verbs, but the truth is in daily speech `я смогу + inf` often means `я сумею + inf`, being a kind of its simplified version, their distinction isn't consistently maintained

Comment: Just a little note. In Ukrainian **Г** is not just a fricative [g], it's a fricative _glottal_ [ɦ].

Comment: speaking of a fricative `г` i think i was guided by the name the  phoneme has in [Russian phonology](http://xn--80afqvalc3ae5i.xn--c1avg/w/index.php?title=%D0%93_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5), unless the article doesn't tell the whole story

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the primary difference is not about 'resiliance VS general ability' but rather between ***суметь*** as 'repeating actions' (iterative) VS ***смочь*** as momentary action.

Most of Russian prefixes usually make a perfective form, which can be iterative or momentary.

Semantically, ***суметь*** comes from ***уметь*** - 'to know how to' - and ***смочь*** goes back to ***мочь*** (may &/or can); therefore it's possible to say

***Я смогу дойти.***

***Я смогу ходить.***

***Я смогу гулять.***

***Я смогу погулять.***

***Я смогу прогуляться.***

but not (or possible just under some specific circumstances)

- ***Я сумею дойти.***
- ***Я сумею ходить.***
- ***Я сумею гулять.***
- ***Я сумею погулять.***
- ***Я сумею пpогуляться.***

The reason is that verbs like ***жить, ходить, играть, дышать*** or ***гулять*** and most of their prefixised forms have habitual connotations, which don't quite get along well with iterative infinitive.

Comment: it doesn't have to be either - or, i think your answer unveils another dimension of the difference between them, that is their relationships with different types of verbs, which i didn't consider... when they're used with the same verb their connotations do slightly differ as in `я смогу прийти вовремя` VS `я сумею прийти вовремя`, the second phrase already implies possibility of some obstacles the speaker might need or is going to overcome in order to be on time

Comment: I meditated over your examples and I have a feeling of "being able again after not being able to" at `я смогу ходить`, there is an implied `снова`, so, like after an injury he toughs up to be able to walk again after rehabilitation. In `я сумею дойти` there is some kind of uniqueness of circumstances, "I will be able to walk this route at -50 and in heavy snow, because I need to fetch a doctor", but not that one has tried this before in a similar setting, although one definitely can walk in general. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Баян Купи-ка : the second phrase is more about (dis)ability than about any obstacles.

Comment: @Oleg Lobachev ; right, but my examples are more about usual context, not any special circumstances (pls see the reference in parentheses).

Comment: disability is an obstacle or a result thereof, isn't it?

Comment: @Баян Купи-ка ; it's neither an obstacle nor an advantage, neither obstacle-and-advantage nor non-obstacle-and-non-advantage :-D

Comment: Those verbs with the prefix _по-_ &/or the suffix _-ива-_ have quite iterative meaning.

Comment: @Yellow Sky; which verbs with the suffix *-ива-* and how come that *по-* in verbs like *поглядеть, посмотреть, подумать* would have any iterative meaning? It's durative.

Comment: ПОглядЫВАть, хажИВАть